# Possibilities of splitting Notepad++ into more than 2 windows

Tags: notepad++, ide

I would like to open 4 Notepad++ windows at once, in the same pannel. Currently, I am only able to split it into two, and would like to know if there is a plugin that enables 4 views at at same time, or 3.

thanks

Comment: Do you mean Notepad++ or Notepadd++?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton nice one. If you are serious, then I meant Notepad++

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, Xlaltra! Much appreciated. I +1'ed your question because I think this would be useful for other people, too.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of out-of-the-box capability, you can right-click on a tab and click on "Move to New Instance". It will create a new Notepad++ window for you. From the new window you can simply create the split columns again.
Personally I find this works well when you have two monitors - you keep one Notepad++ instance per monitor.

Comment: So, you are saying it is not possible unless, I created two windows and two instances within those windows. Well, thanks but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Xlaltra I'm not saying it's *not* possible but that I *don't know* if it is possible - maybe there is a plugin as you mentioned in your question that we do not know about. My answer is an alternative solution that may be acceptable for others (it works for me!). If you do find something please update or answer your own question.