# Notepad++ 3 Views (windows) open?

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ i'm familiar with opening files into new views (Move to Other View). This opens a second window which files can open in. Is there a way to open a 3rd view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notepad++ clone view - more than 2](http://superuser.com/questions/716053/notepad-clone-view-more-than-2), [Possibilities of splitting Notepad++ into more than 2 windows](http://superuser.com/questions/666873/possibilities-of-splitting-notepad-into-more-than-2-windows)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can have a bunch of files opened at the same time; each file is in a different tab. Just use File Open, and select your files. The Move to Other View allows you to see two files side by side.

Added
For viewing more than 2 files side-by-side, you will need to open a second instance of the program and tile the 2 windows so you can see up to 4 files at once.

To open a second instance you can hit Alt+F6: [Open two instances of Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/459705/open-two-instances-of-notepad)

Comment: I already have multiple files open in two views. I have a bunch of files open. My question is how to open a third view. To see three files side by side.

Comment: You didn't say that; how was I to know?

Comment: In my question, I said I'm familiar with Move to Other View. This opens a second view, is there a way to open a 3rd view. Isn't that pretty clear?

Comment: I couldn't find a way; that's why I said to open a second instance and tile the windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opening the first instance, then do the split view, then open another instance and split that view as well. Just to be clear, you basically want to view the same file in three separate views, correct?